# Solution to a 2D recurrence equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am seeking an explicit solution to this 2D recurrence equation:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(0,b) & = & b\\
f(a,0) & = & a\\
f(a,b) & = & f(a-1,b) - f(a,b-1)
\end{eqnarray}
So, for example, for $a=3$,
$$f(3,0)=3 \;,$$
$$f(3,1)=f(2,1)-f(3,0)=-2-3=-5 \;,$$
etc. Here is $f(3,b)$ for $b=0,\ldots,10$:
$$
3, -5, 9, -12, 18, -22, 30, -35, 45, -51, 63 \;.
$$
Note the sums of adjacent terms of this list follow a clear pattern:
$$
-2, 4, -3, 6, -4, 8, -5, 10, -6, 12 \;.
$$

---

[image: Rec2D]

          

<sup>Plot cropped above and below. $f(10,10)=146760$.</sup>

---

Can anyone see or calculate an explicit solution as a function of $(a,b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the generating function $g_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(k,n-k) x^k$.  Thus $g_0(x) = f(0,0) = 0$ and 
$$g_n(x) = n + n x^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (f(k-1,n-k) - f(k,n-1-k)) x^k
= 2n-1 + x^n + (x-1) g_{n-1}(x)$$
which has solution (according to Maple)
$$ g_n(x) = -2\,{\frac {n+1}{x-2}}-{\frac {-x+4}{ \left( x-2 \right) ^{2}}}+{x}^{
n+1}-{\frac {x   \left( -3+x \right)  \left( x-1
 \right) ^{n+1}}{ \left( x-2 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
Despite appearances, this is in fact a polynomial in $x$, i.e. the singularity at $x=2$ is removable.
Then $f(k,m)$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $g_{m+k}(x)$.

Comment: I checked $f(3,1)=-5$. $m+k=n=4$, and $g_4(x) = 4x^4-5x^3+4x^2+x+4$, and indeed the coefficient of $x^3$ is $-5$. Impressive!

Comment: Another instance: $n=10$, $g_{10}(x)=10 x^{10}-44 x^9+114 x^8-193
   x^7+224 x^6-180 x^5+100
   x^4-35 x^3+10 x^2+4 x+10$, and one can check that, e.g., $f(6,4)=224$, which is the coefficient of $x^6$, or $f(7,3)=-193$, which is the coefficient of $x^7$.